# Is there a difference between taskkill /f and C# Process.Kill?

Tags: c#, taskkill

A user is seeing different behaviour between my C# program that uses System.Diagnostics.Process.Kill and the Windows 7 command-line program "taskkill /f".  Possibly the program is dying more cleanly with taskkill

Does "taskkill /f" attempt to issue a WM_CLOSE, SC_CLOSE or WM_QUIT message before resorting to TerminateProcess?  Are there any other pertinent differences?

Comment: What different behavior?

Comment: Hi @ash-burlaczenko.  If you want the gory details: we have an Excel addin talking to an external process.  If we restart the process with "taskkill /f" the addin switches to the new process.  Otherwise the addin doesn't update its connection.  The addin and process are both provided by a third party.  Thanks for the interest