# Difference between taskkill and taskkill /f

Tags: windows, winapi, internals

On [Microsoft Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx) I can read that `taskkill` has a `/f` parameter to kill a process forcefully. I wonder what this does internally, to understand the impact of such an action.

`taskkill` (without `/f`) does not simply send a WM_CLOSE message to the process, otherwise my application would ask whether or not to save the open documents. This makes me assume that it already operates on a [TerminateProcess (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) level. However, `TerminateProcess` does not have a parameter for forcing a kill.

**So, what do `taskkill` and `taskkill /f` do internally?**

I read the related question [Difference between C# Process.Kill() and Taskkill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18701777/is-there-a-difference-between-taskkill-f-and-c-sharp-process-kill) but it does not have an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely `taskkill /f` uses [`TerminateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714(v=vs.85).aspx), where as `taskkill` without `/f` just posts a [WM_QUIT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632641(v=vs.85).aspx) message (not WM_CLOSE). The docs says that `TerminateProcess` unconditionally kills the process.

You can try following experiments:

1. Launch notepad.exe and type a few chars in the notpad window
2. Type `taskkill /f /im notepad.exe`. Notepad will quit immediately

Now do this:

1. Launch notepad.exe and type a few chars in the notpad window
2. Type `taskkill /im notepad.exe`. Notepad won't quit immediately but it will quit ask if you want to save modifiactions.

Comment: Ok, so in the normal case, my application should be able to process all pending Windows Messages but in the `/f` case it can't. Therefore the normal case might not terminate applications that are in "Not Responding" state since "Not responding" means that Windows has detected that the application does not process messages any more.

Comment: A `WM_QUIT` message would be unlikely to cause Notepad to show its "Save modifications?" dialog; by the time `WM_QUIT` is received your main window is usually gone.

Comment: It is *not* `WM_QUIT`, but `WM_CLOSE`, at least on Windows 10, as has been mentioned in a deleted answer.

Comment: Definitively WM_CLOSE is used in Windows 10. It isn't WM_QUIT that is sent.