# How to close aplication with powershell with saving data?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

Some application after closing save some data into its .ini-file.
When I use

```
Stop-Process -Name applictin_name
```

it closing app, but state does not save into .ini

Ho can I correctly close the application with powershell?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with Stop-Process : Stop-Process just kills the process.

Comment: But cmd's taskkill do this correctly, I checked.

Comment: `taskkill` posts a [WM_QUIT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32346660/52598) message. `Stop-Process` is like `taskkill /f`

Comment: You could use something like this `Get-Process applictin_name |  Foreach-Object { $_.CloseMainWindow() | Out-Null }`

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Yes, thank you, this work correctly

Answer (score 0):

It's just a shame it doesn't work in combination with the `if` keyword.

```
$running = Get-Process prog -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if (!$Running){ 
   Get-Process virtualdj |  Foreach-Object { $_.CloseMainWindow() | Out-Null }
}
```